# Issue Setting Variable of Patch in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to modify a variable belonging to a specific patch in NetLogo.

```
set [informed] of target [informed] of target - floor(diff / 2)
```

I get the error: This isn't something you can use "set" on.

'target' is a specific patch I've defined earlier.

I've used syntax like this ([variable-name] of specific-patch) at the end of expressions to define other variables, but it doesn't work when that's the variable you're trying to define.  Removing brackets just results in a different error.  I'm not sure whether I'm missing some major fundamental understanding or some silly syntactic mistake. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `ask target [set informed (informed - floor (diff / 2))]`

Comment: The `set [...] of ...` syntax existed in very old versions of NetLogo but was removed years ago.